# Is there any function / formula available in MS-Excel which can give between CEILING and FLOOR?

Tags: excel, formula

I am looking for a function which can provide me between of CEILING and FLOOR.

For example, If the number is 20.67 it should give me 21 and if the number is 20.33 it should give me 20.

There are thousands rows of data I have and I cannot apply different methods on different columns, like FLOOR on one column and CEILING on other.

Is there anything available which can work out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ROUND()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/round-HP005209239.aspx) - tell it to round to 0 digits, e.g.:

```
=ROUND(11.54,0)
```

will show 12, but

```
=ROUND(11.44,0)
```

will show 11.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, simply use round. The 2nd arugment would always be 0 in your case

`=ROUND(cell_ref,0)`